# Best books for learning number theory and combinatoric.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am a novice programmer. I want to learn basic math on **number theory and         combinatorics**. At first, i want to read basic level books then mid level and high level books on **number theory and combinatorics.**

Can anyone suggest me best books on **number theory and combinatorics** ? ***( step by step basic,mid and high level).***

Comment: There are a number of similar reference questions here. I believe using the search bar will help you. That said, my suggestion concerning number theory would be- "104 Number Theory Problems", https://www.amazon.com/104-Number-Theory-Problems-Training/dp/0817645276

Comment: No. I want to know step by step books on number theory and combinatorics.

Comment: @shakilsorker It is a very step by step approach, demanding no more than high school math..The problems are used as part of the (self)teaching method..Enjoy..

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake .Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Combinatorial Problems and Exercises by Lovasz is an excellent book. In my opinion, the problems are quite difficult, though.